# How to define a rule with a recursive recipe in GNU make?

Tags: recursion, makefile

I want to call make files in subfolders from one top make file.

An example of my top make file that works looks like this, where `buildPath` is a parameter in to the make script:

```
.PHONY: testSystem

testSystem:
    $(MAKE) all -C $(buildPath)/Test1Build
    $(MAKE) all -C $(buildPath)/Test2Build
    $(MAKE) all -C $(buildPath)/Test3Build
```

The problem with this solution is that I have to list all subfolders; Test1Build, Test2Build, Test3Build etc.

Is there a way (with make) to define this rule in such a way that the subfolders in the receipt are recursively found without having to list them all?
...or can I solve this problem in a totally different way?

All subfolders begins with `Test` and ends with `Build` as a pattern.

Comment: The answer is yes, you can. But the technique is too long to describe. I would suggest you to use some ready solution for that, for example my makefile templates: https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about the prorab. I'll have a look a s a p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard at all.  One simple way:

```
testSystem:
        for d in $(buildPath)/*/.; do \
            $(MAKE) all -C $$d; \
        done
```

However, that has many problems.  Much more reliable and robust will be this:

```
subdirs := $(wildcard $(buildPath)/*/.)

testSystem: $(subdirs)

$(subdirs):
        $(MAKE) -C $@ all

.PHONY: testSystem $(subdirs)
```

One caveat: if you use parallel make (`-j`) then you may run into problems with the second solution if the results of the subdirectories depend on each other.  If they do then you'll have to declare these dependency relationships in your makefile:

```
$(buildPath)/foo/. : $(buildPath)/bar/.
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll test your suggestions a s a p. It's a great feeling to learn something new.

Comment: I've now tested your make script and it works perfect. I had to change your wildcard definition so that it only filtered out the folders that actually contains a make file. Otherwise it stops with the error "No target found matching all". Thanks a lot!